# json array to javascript array and throw it to autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON array like this coming back as a server response

```
[{"label":"Casa Grande Trinity","idx":"14710"},{"label":"Ceebros Venkatadri","idx":"14711"},{"label":"Devinarayan Sai Saga","idx":"14712"},{"label":"Estancia","idx":"14713"},{"label":"gujarat properties","idx":"14714"},{"label":"Hi Teckno Shravan","idx":"14715"},{"label":"IPDEV","idx":"14716"},{"label":"Nahar Mangalam","idx":"14718"},{"label":"Offer Image","idx":"14719"},{"label":"Pushkar s gosel gard","idx":"14721"},{"label":"Pushkars Grace","idx":"14722"},{"label":"Rams Anjali Atrium","idx":"14723"},{"label":"Sai sagar adyar","idx":"14724"},{"label":"Utopia","idx":"14730"},{"label":"VJS The Monarch","idx":"14731"}]
```

SO I want to convert it into JavaScript array with same structure

and i want to use the resultant array in auto complete.

Comment: This is indeed a JavaScript Array (of objects). What your JavaScript array should contain ?

Comment: that'a an array already, and also can you specify which field you want to use for auto complet?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want an array of strings and the strings would be the label project of each of those objects. If so, you can use the power of `map` like so:

```
var autoComplete = response.map(function(record) {
 return record.label;
});
```

Where response corresponds with your example array. However, it completely depends on what format the autocomplete implementation you are using expects. If it simply wants an array of potential autocomplete strings, then `autoComplete` will work.

MDN: [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
    $(function() {
    var data=[{"label":"Casa Grande Trinity","idx":"14710"},{"label":"Ceebros Venkatadri","idx":"14711"},{"label":"Devinarayan Sai Saga","idx":"14712"},{"label":"Estancia","idx":"14713"},{"label":"gujarat properties","idx":"14714"},{"label":"Hi Teckno Shravan","idx":"14715"},{"label":"IPDEV","idx":"14716"},{"label":"Nahar Mangalam","idx":"14718"},{"label":"Offer Image","idx":"14719"},{"label":"Pushkar s gosel gard","idx":"14721"},{"label":"Pushkars Grace","idx":"14722"},{"label":"Rams Anjali Atrium","idx":"14723"},{"label":"Sai sagar adyar","idx":"14724"},{"label":"Utopia","idx":"14730"},{"label":"VJS The Monarch","idx":"14731"}];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: data
    });
  });
```

HTML :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vikashvverma/d91ze81j/

Comment: the json array is the response from the php page on ajax call .

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(msg);
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                    x[i]=jsonData[i];
                   }
console.log(x);
```

this solved my issue